# iterate over a list of colums to print out the .value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of columns i want to iterate over to get the .value_counts() for each column , getting errors or the code i posted in the bottom i get no printing at all

```
x = [ 'call_type','date_time','FullAddress','priority']

for i in range(len(x)):
    df[x[i]].value_counts()
```

this is with one single column name

```
df["call_type"].value_counts()

415         22303
459A        21045
1150        17070
1151        12884
911         11094
CW           9458
586          9405
5150         7109
415V         6922
1016         6453
MCTSTP       5818
1185         5682
FU           5179
1186         5101
415N         5066
SELENF       4787
FD           4435
SLEEPER      3885
INFO         3511
REPORT       3390
1153         3264
PARTY        3170
10851R       2923
602          2877
242          2831
459R         2825
AU2          2802
CC           2776
415PP        2528
488R         2525
```

Comment: please do add some sample data too which matches the counts

Comment: What is error here?

Comment: sorry i was not printing

Comment: please dont vote me down

Comment: @jezrael please dont vote me down , was not using print

Comment: @anky_91 sorry was not using print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just generating data, but not telling your function to print the data to the console.

Add the `print()` function

```
x = ['call_type','date_time','FullAddress','priority']

for i in range(len(x)):
    print(df[x[i]].value_counts())
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution should working, also is possible simplify:

```
for i in x:
    print(df[i].value_counts())
```

Comment: can you explain why ` 
for i in range(len(x)):
    df[x[i]].value_counts()` did not work

Answer (score 0):

Also,

```
for col in df.columns:
    print(df[col].value_counts())
```

or,

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).T.stack()
```